# Firestore authentication asking to select "android/ios" or "web" for kivy app

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, kivy, kivy-language

I'm just setting up a firebase database for my kivy app and the first thing I need to do is "add an app to get started", the choices being IOS, Android, Web or Unity. Is this saying that I need to set up and maintain code for an Android-Kivy app and an IOS-Kivy app? The idea behind Kivy is that it is write once, use everywhere so I'm hoping to just have one version.

Or have I misunderstood this part?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target both Android and iOS for any cross-platform development tool (not just Kivy), you will need to add both an Android and iOS app to your Firebase project.  Firebase doesn't know anything about Kivy (or Flutter, or Unity), so you have to tell it which OS is being targeted.

Comment: What do you mean by add both an android and iOS app to my project? I'm writing in python but does this mean I need to use swift for the IOS app? Sorry for the noob question

Comment: I'm saying that if you want to produce an iOS app, and you're using Firebase, you have to add an iOS app to your project in the console.  Same for Android.  It doesn't matter how you build the the actual app, but the app for each platform must be registered separately in the Firebase project.

Comment: Ok so I can create both the iOS and Android with firebase using Kivy/python but I just have to duplicate the files for linking to Firebase. One for Android and one for ios?

Comment: I suppose. I've never used kivy.

Comment: Is this step (adding firebase to an app), the last step, once the app has been deployed on android and ios phones? I am currently in development stage so do I leave this for now?

Comment: You should do it first.